# Nouns with different meaning in the plural form. How to use them on plural sentences?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, plural-forms, nouns

I was wondering myself how to use the nouns which have different meaning in the plural form on plural sentences, for example the word:

> Blind - Blinds

If I want to refer to more than one `Blind`, Should I use `Blind` or `Blinds`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'different meaning'? The thing that I pull down at my window is a blind. Two of them are blinds. There is no change of meaning.

Comment: @tunny Ohhh I see, So this is all about the context and  how do we use the word (noun,adjective,verb etc)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Plural of [blind](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blind) (verb) is 'blind'. For example,

> Thick shrubs **blind** my downstairs windows

However for something singular you would say 'blinds'. For example,

> Detecting glaucoma before it **blinds** you

But in case of 'Blind' (noun) 'that we use in our homes' you will need to use 'blinds' for the plural, for example:

> There are many different kinds of **window blinds**

Comment: What about "Detecting glaucoma before it make you go blind?"

Comment: "Detecting glaucoma before it makes you go blind" sounds about right, too.

Comment: The original question was about nouns, not verbs.

Comment: @tunny Okay, I edited my answer to include both 'noun' and 'verb'.